# How to decrpyt blowfish CBC data in pure python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, blowfish, cbc-mode

I'm trying to decrpyt blowfish CBC (Cipher Block Chaining) encrypted data in Python 2.7. I tried [this module](https://github.com/JarrodCTaylor/steganopy/blob/master/src/blowfish.py) but it does not accept byte strings as initialization vector like [pycrypto](https://github.com/dlitz/pycrypto), only integers. My initialization vector exists as byte string and it works with pycrypto.
But the decryption is needed within a kodi plugin and kodi allows only pure python scripts. It's not possible to compile for example pycrypto.
How can I implement the blowfish CBC decrytion in Python 2.7?

Comment: Of course Blowfish is no longer considered secure and should not be used, especially in new code. Even it's author uses AES.

Comment: It can be but it's not possible for me to use for example AES because the blowfish cec encrypted data already exists and I try to decode it.

Comment: Ah yes, compatibility always seems to win over security. So disappointing.